# How to register a new user from android client on Ejabberd server

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api

How can I register a new user from android client on Ejabberd Server?
Are there a rest API to solve this issue?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you enable account registration in mod_register configuration, you can use XMPP's In-Band-Registration.

Alternatively, you can run the ejabberd command "register" with several alternative ways, if you enable ejabberd_xmlrpc, mod_http_api, or mod_rest. See https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/managing/#ejabberd-commands